# Twiml voice response to incoming call not working after record start

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I want to record an incoming call request(both sides), and than say some line.

my webhook response to incmong call is:

```
        $response = new VoiceResponse;
        $response->record([
            'action' => 'http://example.com',
            'timeout' => '180',
            'recordingStatusCallback' => 'http://example2.com',
        ]);
        $response->say("hello world!", array('voice' => 'alice'));
        return $response;
```

which give the following twiml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Record action="http://example.com" timeout="180" recordingStatusCallback="http://example2.com"/>
   <Say voice="alice">hello world!</Say>
</Response>
```

the problem I face is the "Hello world" not play, if I remove the `$response->record` part then the "Hello world" work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<Record>` TwiML verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record) is used to take a recording of the person on the phone, like in a voicemail situation. The `<Record>` verb will effectively block and not execute any other TwiML until the recording is complete, then it will make a request to the URL in the `action` attribute, so your `<Say>` will never be executed.

If you are trying to record a voicemail, then I recommend putting the `<Say>` first and instructing the caller to leave their message after a beep.

```php
$response = new VoiceResponse;
$response->say("Hello world! Please leave your message after the beep.", array('voice' => 'alice'));
$response->record([
    'action' => 'http://example.com',
    'timeout' => '180',
    'recordingStatusCallback' => 'http://example2.com',
]);
return $response;
```

If you are trying to record the entire incoming call from the beginning, you need to [use the REST API to start the recording](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#create-a-recording-resource).

If you are trying to do something else with the call, please comment below and I'll try to help out.

Comment: I am trying to record the whole incoming call, including all the says and gather, without stopping the recording I want to hear the say words in the recording

Comment: Then you need to use the REST API to start the recording, check the link near the bottom of my answer.

Comment: so the flow is like:
incoming call -> received webhook -> send api request with the call sid to start recording

Comment: That's correct. Then your TwiML can continue to control the call, but Twilio will record everything that is going on.